# Promise.all. Обработка ошибки

Tags: javascript, promise

Всем привет!
Предположим что делаются асинхронные запросы на сервер, и в `prom2` некорректно пришел ответ от сервера
500 ошибка. А в `Promise.all` ожидается выполнение всех промисов и соответственно,
если в `prom2`  произошла ошибка, то `Promise.all` будет отклонен.
Отсюда вопрос, каким образом можно описать функцию, чтобы если в `prom2` ошибка, то
получали `null` или `"error!"` в `Promise.all [data, null, data]`. Что-то у меня вообще идей не возникло, как обработать некорректный запрос, чтобы `Promise all` не был отклонен.
Я нашел метод Promise.allSettled(), но это вроде не то

```js
let prom1 = new Promise()//data
let prom2 = new Promise()//500 
let prom3 = new Promise()//data

Promise.all([prom1, prom2, prom3])//[data, null, data]
```

Comment: `Promise.allSettled()` как раз то, что вам нужно. Подробнее: https://learn.javascript.ru/promise-api#promise-allsettled

Comment: Я уже придумал как можно обойтись без данного метода:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть кому-то пригодится.

```
let a = Promise.resolve(200)
let b = Promise.reject(400)
let c = Promise.resolve(200)


Promise.all([a, b, c].map((item) =>  item.catch(x => (x)? 'error': x))).then(arr => console.log(arr))
```